# Is there a way to utilize React's `history.push()` to trigger a file download?

Tags: reactjs

## Context

I'm trying to have a button trigger a download -- the `<Button/>` component within the codebase I'm working with does not support `href`, so I can't do something simple like `href="/files/${id}.csv"`. I thought I could use something like the `history()` API to fetch a file, but it's appending `.json` to the end of my file and isn't working.

- What am I doing wrong or misunderstanding about `history`?
- If this isn't possible, what might be a better way to achieve my goal?

### What I've Tried

I have the following code within a functional component:

```js
handleCSVDownload = id => () => {
  const { history } = props;
  history.push(`/files/${id}.csv`);
}

const { fileId } = props;
<Button onClick={handleCSVDownload(fileId)}>Download File<Button/>
```

I would expect onClick to have the CSV download dialog appear.

However, this doesn't happen and I get a 404 w/ `.json` added to the URL:

```js
GET http://localhost/files/1234.csv.json 404 (Not Found)
                                   ^^^^^
```

**NOTE**: Additionally, another odd thing is, if I hit "back" in my browser, I'll then be prompted for the file download, despite the URL not resolving onClick.

### Question

Why is `.json` appended to my CSV link? Can someone help me better understand `history` under the hood in relation to why my code might not be working as expected? Any thoughts on a better solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know which library do you use for *history*.
But I could suggest a maybe simple solution using  window.open() function, it will trigger file downloading

```
handleCSVDownload = id => () => {

  window.open(`/files/${id}.csv`, "_blank");
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this! You're right, using *history* is unnecessary and this worked well! I just changed it to `_self` instead of `_blank` so it opens in the same tab (to mirror the page's previous behavior prior to my updating this button). Thanks for taking the time to read my question and submitting your answer! 